# Android - Simultaneous multiselect on two listviews

Tags: android, listview, multi-select, cab

I have two separated ListViews (btw dynamically created in a custom adapter, but that shouldn't be a problem) and I can't find a way to be able to multiselect items from both the listviews simultaneously.

I've already tried with setItemChecked on single click even, but, due to the CAB's method onItemCheckedStateChanged, the old checked items deselect themselves in favour of the new listview. This way I've also tried to disable CAB auto-creation & deletion, but I haven't found a way out.